# flickering issue with Mddialog in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using MDDialog in my angular app.whenever user click on the div ,

- Flickering is happening
- after that, if the user clicks on the one of the buttons, the afterclose event is not raised.

Can someone suggest me what should i do to avoid above issues?

calling dialog:

```
    private openialog(data) {

      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { width: 
              '350px', height: '100px', disableClose: true});
      dialogRef.updatePosition({ top: '95px' });

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

      this.dialogResult = result;

      console.log('dialogResult : ' + this.dialogResult);

      if (this.dialogResult) {
            this.Home();
        }

      });
      this.dialogResult = '';
     }
```

Dialog html:

```
 <div md-autofocus>
   <div md-dialog-container>
   <h2 md-dialog-title>Information</h2>
   <md-dialog-content> Do you want to proceed? </md-dialog-content>
   <div md-dialog-actions>
      <div class="dialogButtons">
         <button  id= "YesButton" class="dialogButton"
            (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">Yes</button>
         <span class="flex1margin"></span>
         <button   id="NoButton" class="dialogButton"  
            (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">No</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Dialog Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
selector: 'your-dialog-selector',
templateUrl: './dialog.component.html'
})
export class DialogComponent {
     constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<any>) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is typo when you're calling `.close()` method on dialog object. `dailogRef` should be `dialogRef`

```
 <button  id= "YesButton" class="dialogButton"
    (click)="dailogRef.close(true)">Yes</button>
 <span class="flex1margin"></span>
 <button   id="NoButton" class="dialogButton"  
    (click)="dailogRef.close(false)">No</button>
 </div>
```

should be

```
 <button  id= "YesButton" class="dialogButton"
    (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">Yes</button>
 <span class="flex1margin"></span>
 <button   id="NoButton" class="dialogButton"  
    (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">No</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry It was my typo.. I can still see the issue after correcting it.

Comment: Can you please add plunker/ stackblitz here with issue reproducible in it..